If an algebra includes an isomorphic algebra, are they equal?
Let A and B be isomorphic subalgebras of the same algebra. If A is contained in B, does it follow that A=B?
Specifically, I am interested in algebras of smooth ($C^\infty-$) functions from a phase space to the reals, defined the requirements that they are closed under products $(f \circ g)(m) := f(m)g(m)$, linear combinations $(af + b)(m) := af(m) + bg(m)$, and contain the unit function, whose output is always 1.

This is also not true for simpler structures like groups and rings. For example, the group $2\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$; the ring $\mathbb Z[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[x_2,x_4,x_6,\dots]$. The ring example actually answers your question, since rings and (associative, unital) $\mathbb Z$-algebras are the same thing.

All that isomorphic to a (strict) subobject (with a functor to the category Set) tells you is that the object is infinite.  (There's an old definition of infinite set that is pretty much "equicardinal with a strict subset".)

Related: A ring isomorphic to a proper subring of itself? In the linked post, the example of $\mathbb Z[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]$ and $\mathbb Z[x_2,x_4,x_6,\dots]$ is given. More generally, if $k$ is a commutative ring (in particular, if $k$ is a field), then $k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ and $k[x_2,x_4,x_6,\dots]$ are isomorphic as $k$-algebras (and the latter is a proper subring of the former, provided that $k\neq0$). This doesn't give an example of algebras of smooth functions, though.

No. Let $B = C(\mathbb{T})$, the algebra of continuous functions on the unit circle. Let $A = \{f \in B: f(z) = f(-z), \forall z \in \mathbb{T}\}$. Then $A$ is a subalgebra of $B$ that is isomorphic to $B$ (as the unit circle, quotient out by the equivalence relation generated $z \sim -z$ for all $z \in \mathbb{T}$, is homeomorphic to the unit circle), but $A \neq B$.

The same holds if you change continuous functions to smooth functions, since the unit circle is also diffeomorphic to its two-fold covering space.
